# Que valor tiene this en typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

He tratado de entender cual es el significado de this en typescript, pero aun no lo comprendo. Estoy aprendiendo Angular y por lo que he leido this se refiere al objeto, pero en otros casos a la propiedad. Lo siento estoy confundido :S Por ejemplo tengo este componente.

```js
class Camiseta{
  marca: string

  constructor(marca:string){
    this.marca = marca;
  }
    var camiseta = new Camiseta("Rebook");
    console.log(camiseta.marca);
};
```

¿Cual es el valor de this?

Comment: En el ejemplo se refiere al objeto. ¿Cuál es el caso que mencionas en el que se refiere a una propiedad?

Comment: Si estoy refiriendo al objeto ¿Porque no puedo escribir camiseta.marca = marca; En vez de this.marca = marca;

Comment: Porque estás dentro del objeto. Si lo haces desde afuera si podrías hacerlo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la propiedad ``camiseta`` no existe dentro de la clase ``Camiseta`` por lo tanto, no la encuentra. Si quieres hacer eso, tienes que crear una propiedad llamada ``camiseta: Camiseta`` y en el constructor asignarle el valor de ``this``. Por cierto, tienes un ``var`` y un ``console.log`` dentro de la clase (eso da un **Syntax Error**)